# How to avoid impossible enum values?

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Say I have the following enum:

```
[Flags]
enum IntFlags
{
  A = 1 << 0,
  B = 1 << 1,
  C = 1 << 2,

  AAndB = A | B
}
```

and I want to build a helper method that sets flags like the following:

```
private static IntFlags Set(IntFlags values, IntFlags target)
{
  return target | values;
}
```

Is there any flexible way to do some sanity checking? Like it should be impossible to set values that don't exist in the enum or are not a combination of existing values.

Stuff like the following should not be possible:

```
IntFlags flags = 0;
flags = Set(0, flags);
flags = Set((IntFlags)int.MaxValue, flags);
flags = Set(~IntFlags.A, flags);
```

I guess just doing a check against the existing values like:

```
private static IntFlags Set(IntFlags values, IntFlags target)
{
  if (!Enum.GetValues(typeof(IntFlags)).Cast<IntFlags>().Contains(values))
    throw new ArgumentException();

  return target | values;
}
```

won't work because setting values like

```
IntFlags flags = 0;
flags = Set(IntFlags.A | IntFlags.C, flags);
```

should be allowed.

I think this might work:

```
IntFlags Set(IntFlags values, IntFlags target)
{      
  int intValue;
  if (int.TryParse(values.ToString(), out intValue))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException();
  }

  ...
 }
```

but this relies on the fact that I'm using the Flags attribute on the enum.

**Edit**

I now found the Enum.IsDefined() method. It works nicely with

```
Assert.False(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IntFlags), (IntFlags)int.MaxValue));
Assert.False(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IntFlags), 0));
Assert.False(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IntFlags), ~IntFlags.A));
```

but fails my requirements with combined values

```
Assert.True(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IntFlags), IntFlags.A | IntFlags.C)); //fails
```

Comment: As a rough concept, assuming that your enum backing type is always int, you could enumerate the available values, then OR them all together.  This creates a mask that includes all possible flag combinations.  You can then AND your value against the negation of the mask; if the result is non-zero, it's outside the allowed range.  Though, to be fair, does it really matter if the value contains bits outside the defined flags range?

Comment: Don't use an enum - have static references that you explicitly control the creation of them.

Comment: Ok, 10 mins after posting i stumbled upon the Enum.IsDefined method. It seems to do what I want and doesn't require the Flags attribute.

Comment: I don't understand why your first solution won't work. [It works for me](http://ideone.com/H9j2Jx) and allows `IntFlags.A | IntFlags.B`

Comment: My bad, that should be Set(IntFlags.A | IntFlags.C, flags); instead of Set(IntFlags.A | IntFlags.B, flags). I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to statically prohibit users of an `Enum` from creating an enum representing any value of the underlying type.  You can only do such validation at runtime, as you showed in the question.

If you're just looking for a simple enough way of validating, at runtime, if a particular enum value is a valid combination of flags, then that's a simple enough check, assuming the defined enum values are actually increasing powers of two.  For such an enum all valid values will go from zero to one less than the next highest power of two, so the check would become:

```
if((int)values > 0 && (int)values >= 1 << 3))
    throw new ArgumentException();
```

Technically you could remove all possible unmapped values by must mapping every single value, but that's  not a particularly *practical* solution.

All that you're left with if either of those aren't an option is to not use an `Enum`, but to instead use your own custom type that has the exact semantics you want:

```
public class IntFlags
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    private IntFlags(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static readonly IntFlags A = new IntFlags(1);
    public static readonly IntFlags B = new IntFlags(2);
    public static readonly IntFlags C = new IntFlags(4);

    public static IntFlags operator |(IntFlags first, IntFlags second)
    {
        return new IntFlags(first.Value | second.Value);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as IntFlags);
    }
    public override bool Equals(IntFlags obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Value == obj.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding non-existing values statically surely is the safest way. +1

Answer (score 1):

Having a static IntFlag field where you actually add these values is a good solution and as you realized we do have a `Enum.IsDefined` but just FYI, you can go the bit masking way as well. I threw up something together in LINQPad to give you an idea:

BitVector32 is in System.Collections.Specialized

```
[Flags]
enum IntFlags
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1 << 0,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,

    AAndB = A | B
}

void Main()
{
    BitVector32 bv = new BitVector32(0);
    int mask1 = BitVector32.CreateMask();
    int mask2 = BitVector32.CreateMask(1 << 0);
    int mask3 = BitVector32.CreateMask(1 << 1);
    int mask4 = BitVector32.CreateMask(1 << 2);

    bv[mask1 + mask2 + mask3 + mask4] = true;

    //IntFlags flag1 = IntFlags.A | IntFlags.C;
    IntFlags flag1 = (IntFlags)int.MaxValue;
    if((bv.Data & (int)flag1) == (int)flag1)
        "Yes".Dump();
    else
        "No".Dump();
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a tiny problem when I run this with 0 because it says Yes even when I don't have None in my flags. But I think I'll simply catch this special case explicitly. The rest seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @user764754 Yes. Notice that I added None = 0 in flags. It's always a good idea to have None I think.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `[Flags]` enum has individual values that are single bits, something like this should do you:

```
public static Foo SetBits( Foo foo , Foo bar )
{
  Foo value = foo | bar ;

  // throw if any bits are set that are not set in the enum itself.      
  bool isValid = value == (AllBits&value) ;
  if ( !isValid ) throw new InvalidOperationException() ;

  return value ;
}

// Bitwise OR of all bits of all defined values for the enum
private static readonly Foo AllBits = (Foo) Enum
                                      .GetValues(typeof(Foo))
                                      .Cast<int>()
                                      .Aggregate( (x,y) => x|y )
                                      ;
```